# Unable to change font color only when the text is overlapping with a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs, html5-canvas

I'm trying to change the font color to white only when the **selector** is overlapping the text and couldn't find a solution.

The wanted behavior is the following one:

1. Change the font color to white only when the selector is
   overlapping.
2. Grow the font size of the active tab to 18px
3. The selector should move to the active tab.

I have tried a few things and none seems to work.

This is what I have right now: https://codepen.io/galanflorind/pen/gOpQKPP

```js
var tabs = $('.tabs');
var selector = $('.tabs').find('a').length;
var activeItem = tabs.find('.active');
var activeWidth = activeItem.innerWidth();
$(".selector").css({
  "left": activeItem.position.left + "px", 
  "width": activeWidth + "px"
});

$(".tabs").on("click","a",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.tabs a').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass('active');
  var activeWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
  var itemPos = $(this).position();
  $(".selector").css({
    "left":itemPos.left + "px", 
    "width": activeWidth + "px"
  });
  
// Temporary fix for resizing after the transition is done
// TODO: find another solution
  setTimeout(() => {
    var activeWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
    var itemPos = $(this).position();
    $(".selector").css({
    "left":itemPos.left + "px", 
    "width": activeWidth + "px"
  });
    }, 401)
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

body{
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.wrapper{
  text-align:center;
  margin:50px auto;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

.tabs{
  font-size:15px;
  padding:0px;
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50px;
  position:relative;
}

.tabs a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #2f3059;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  padding:6px 20px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.tabs a.active{
  color:#fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.tabs .selector{
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  background: #3e40db;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  z-index:1;
  border-radius: 16px;
  transition: width 1s, .6s;
  transition-timing-function: easeOutCirc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav class="tabs">
    <div class="selector"></div>
    <a href="#" class="active">WHOLESALE SUPPLY</a>
    <a href="#">E-LEARNING</a>
    <a href="#">MEDICAL COMPLIANCE</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

There is something similar on the Stripe website - https://stripe.com/en-nl/sigma
[image: Screenshot Stripe]

Comment: `only when the selector is overlapping` What selector?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the selector is basically the div that looks like a button, couldn't find a better naming.
Check the HTML code

Comment: That doesn't really help. The goal of your question is not at all clear.

Comment: To clarify, it seems that you want a div to move over the top of a selected nav item (via an animation) but instead of having the nav item's font fade out during the animation like it does now, it should only turn white after the div has started to cover the text. @Florin G, s that right? If so, do you want to keep the fade or are you trying to set it white immediately once the text is covered?

Comment: @tlong314 something like that but I wanna set the text white immediately once is covered (character by character), just like in a loading bar.
And if you have **WHOLESALE SUPPLY** selected and click on **MEDICAL COMPLIANCE** when the blue div will start to hover the **middle nav item** it would change the text color to white (character by character and not the whole word).Makes sense?
If you look closely on https://stripe.com/en-nl/sigma is exactly what I wanna reproduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no great simple way to do this. A quick right-click->Inspect shows that even the site you reference actually uses a `<canvas>` animation to draw the entire effect (i.e., it's not CSS- it's just a picture). Here are some options, but they are either not quite complete, or will take a long time to implement.

Option 1.) The quickest way to get a similar effect would be to add the CSS property mix-blend-mode: screen; to your links and remove the `color: #fff;` rule. However, the new color will look somewhat faded:

```css
.tabs a {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

Option 2.) Create an animation with `<canvas>` as the referenced site does, or animated gifs that change when the user clicks the tabs area. Either of these processes will take a long time, as you either have to create the images or code the animation.

Option 3.) Wrap every single letter in a `<span>` and use setTimeouts in your JavaScript to set up when to change the color of each, based on the length of your animation and which direction the selector is going (or set up CSS animations for each one if you don't mind them fading rather than immediately changing color). One issue here is that the entire letter will change color at once instead of just a bit of it at a time.

Option 4.) If you have complete control over the positioning and sizing of the nav elements, you can reproduce the effect by writing A LOT of CSS (so I won't try to figure out the entire thing here, but I will explain how to do it). This might be more work than is worth it.

Create a copy of each link, say, create two spans in each hyperlink, with the same text in each span.
Position the spans directly over each other so that the corresponding texts overlap (i.e., you should not be able to see the text on bottom).

Set the bottom layer span text color to white, and top span to #3e40db. CSS `clip-path` property is animatable, so you can use CSS animations to hide the top span layer as the selector div moves over it (since you have control over the element sizes, transition time, and animation time, you should be able to do this with enough time put into it). Basically `clip-path` can "clip out" a rectangular area of what is being shown in an element, so if you have to overlapping divs, then making that rectangular area smaller/larger with controlled animations you can control exactly when a horizontal rectangular area of the top is being hidden (i.e. the bottom is being shown). Again, the main issue is that this will take a LOT of code and a long time to write/implement, because you have to perfect the absolute positioning, the timing, AND account for the if the selector is moving left or right over a div. But if you are willing to put in the time and work, the basic setup will look something like this:

```css
@keyframes clip-animation-from-left {
    0% {
       clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 300px, 0px 300px);
    }

    50% {
        clip-path: polygon(150px 0px, 300px 0px, 300px 300px, 150px 300px);
    }

    100% {
        clip-path: polygon(300px 0px, 300px 0px, 300px 300px, 300px 300px);
    }
}


/* You'll have to rewrite some JavaScript to add/remove classes determining which way the selector is coming */
.tabs a.active-from-left {
    animation-name: clip-animation-from-left;
    animation-duration: .4s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to have every single character be its own html element to be able to change its color.

There's no CSS property to change the color of only some lettes of a button.

Be careful if you care about accesibility, that will ruin it for screen readers. Would advise against it. However, if is temporary and only happens during the animation it could be ok.